# Mapping the Number of Functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

I have read here how to figure out the number of functions between two sets A and B. But how do I figure the number of ways a function can be expressed within a another function. For example:

(Let's say A has 2 elements and B has 3)

f is the function from A to B
g is the function from B to A

How many possible functions in     $f$ o $g$?

Comment: It’s possible to have two different pairs $\langle f_i,g_i\rangle$, $i=1,2$, such that $f_1\circ g_1=f_2\circ g_2$, but $\langle f_1,g_1\rangle\ne\langle f_2,g_2\rangle$. Do you count this situation as one function or as two?

Comment: As two I believe...

Comment: Suppose that there are $m$ functions from $A$ to $B$ and $n$ from $B$ to $A$. You can compose any of the $m$ with any of the $n$, so there must be $mn$ possible compositions. Some of them will be the same function, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the easy case: for every $h:A \to A$, we can find an $f,g$ with $f:A\to B$ and $g:B \to A$ such that $g \circ f = h$.  This is because the number of elements in $A$ is less than (or equal to) the number of elements in $B$.  I suggest you try to prove that this is the case.

Now, to directly address your question: if $h:B \to B$, we can write $h = f \circ g$ if and only if the image of $h$ contains at most 2 elements (the number of elements in $A$). I suggest you try to prove that this is the case.

What this means for us (for this particular choice of $A$ and $B$) is that the kinds of maps we're counting are those that are *not* permutations of $B$ (which are the maps whose image has more than $2$ elements).  So, we end up with a total of 
$$
3^3 - 3! = 27 - 6 = 21
$$
such maps.

In general, if $A$ has $m$ elements and $B$ has $n$ with $m<n$, then we are counting the number of ways in which $n$ distinct balls can be placed in at most $m$ out of $n$ distinct urns.  With the first [stars and bars formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), our total will be
$$
\sum_{k =1}^m \frac{n!}{k!}\binom{n - 1}{k-1} = 
n^n - \sum_{k =m+1}^n \frac{n!}{k!}\binom{n - 1}{k-1}
$$